# In "Attention Is All You Need", why are the FFNs in (2) the same as two convolutions with kernel size 1?

Tags: convolution, transformer, attention-mechanism, research

In addition, why do we need a FFN in each layer when we already have attention?

Here's a screenshot of the relevant section from Vaswani et al. (2017):

[image: eScreenshot of relevant section from Vaswani et al. (2017)]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A position-wise feedforward layer is just a matrix multiplication plus the addition of a bias vector for each position along the time dimension. You can express this as a 1D convolution of kernel size 1. This was first suggested by [Lin et al. (2014)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1312.4400), who called it "network in network".

Given that the position-wise feedforward network is the concatenation of 2 feedforward layers, you can express it as two 1D convolutions of kernel size 1.

Answer (score 0):

Convolution is actually applying a sliding window projection over a tensor. With the kernel size of 1, the convolution reduces a to a for loop over the vectors, i.e., each of the vectors gets multiplied by a filter matrix. But this is actually a definition of matrix multiplication which is how feed-forward layers are implemented.